# Android Seekbar as Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-seekbar

I'm creating button to change the volume and i want that `onClick`, a `seekbar` appears as a sort of `dialog`(*but not the one that covers the screen and does not allow interaction with other elements on the screen*) below the button and it should disappear after a few seconds.I do not want to use the `alertDialog` that the **android** provides as that covers the whole activity.How do I go about this? Also is there any library to achieve this?

Comment: Can You Please send screenshot how seelbar is looking and how you want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your seekBar below your button in your xml layout with alpha="0", and try:

```
    SeekBar mSeekbar;
    int delay = 1000;
    Button mButton;
    Handler mHandler;
    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            anim.setDuration(500);
            mSeekbar.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    };


    //inside onCreate (or wherever you decide)
    mHandler = new Handler(); //(android.os)
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, delay);
        }
    });


    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mSeekbar.getAlpha() == 0) {
                Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, delay);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                mSeekbar.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: the seekbar does not appear.are you sure animation works as expected?

Comment: verify that you not set it's visibility to 'gone' and that you set animation's duration

Answer (score 1):

you can use `WindowManager` to add your `SeekBar` to the window and at the same time you can interact with your activity or other also. Post one handler to remove that view after specified time.

```
        View yourSeekBarView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_xml,null,false);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                150,
                50,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);  
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL |Gravity.TOP;      
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(oView, params);
```

---

```
wm.removeView(yourSeekBarView);
```